# Unknown column error on Mysql insert query

Tags: mysql, insert

```
When doing a simple insert into an MYSQL database, I get this error
```

"Unknown column 'Af452OtQa' in 'field list'"

'Af452OtQa' is the value that I'm attempting to insert into the column 'serialnum'  All the variables are set from POST values from the previous page, and all are urlencoded except for this field, which I create the value for and thus, know that it won't have anything but alphanumerics in it.

```
      $insertSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO Presentations ('serialnum', 'docurl', 'tracker', 'recipient', 'last_accessed') VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s,)",
  $sn,$doc,$trackr,$recip,$lastacc);
```

Comment: you forgot the quotes, he consider your value to be a column

Answer (score 2):

Isn't there an extra comma in your SQL statement?

You need quotes in the values clause, not the column names portion of the insert

```
$insertSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO Presentations "+
                               "(serialnum, docurl, tracker, recipient, last_accessed) "+
                               "VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s')",
                                $sn,$doc,$trackr,$recip,$lastacc);
```

Also: Have you thought about using the bind variables, because your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks.

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that.  I thought that's what using the %s variables did.